# ImageResizer S3Reader2 Plugin 404 Error after image has been uploaded

Tags: amazon-s3, imageresizer

We have been using ImageResizer serving images from disk for quite a while and it has been a great product for us!

Now we are trying to upgrade services to scale and using S3 for storage and running into a major issue for us.

If the image does not exist at S3 there is an AWSSDK error being thrown, that looks like is then preventing the image from ever being loaded through ImageResizer and continues to throw 404 even after the image has been loaded to S3.

To replicate the problem simply have S3Reader2 plugin running and try to pull up an image that does not exist in S3. Then load the image to S3 and it will not load the image unless you restart the application pool.

Info you likely want/need to help troubleshoot:

- [ImageResizer diagnostic output](https://gist.github.com/studiothat/3fd18b967472783318cc)
- [The Exception being thrown when running in Visual Studio](https://gist.github.com/studiothat/2249aa587ad8b0bb5d06)

Anyone else run into this? is there a workaround?

Comment: Does the same AmazonS3Exception occur even after the image is uploaded to S3 and directly accessible by your browser? Which browser version/platform are you using, and what network request information is shown before and after the image is uploaded?

Comment: No there is no AmazonS3Exception after the images is uploaded S3, but subsequent calls for the same file don't throw the AmazonS3Exception if the file isn't there either, just the first time. It's as if the image site caches on 404 error and continues to just show 404 error until I restart the app. I've tested in chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit) and firefox 38.0.5.

Comment: Nathanael, have you had a chance to look at this any further? This is a critical issue preventing us from using S3 plugin.

Comment: But the server does get the request? It's not cached by the browser? What is the HTTP status code response on subsequent requests?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `cacheMetadata="false"`, which is a v4+ configuration parameter.

You are using the v3.4.3 dlls. Upgrading to v4 should resolve the issue. v3 does not have a way to fully disable metadata caching (Sliding expiration defaults to 1 hour).

Comment: Thanks. didn't realize the doc's default to v4 now. Any hints as to when v4 might become stable/official?