# ImageResizer s3Reader2 not cache-busting correclty

Tags: imageresizer

1. [gist of my diagnostic output (includes resizer config)](https://gist.github.com/jdc0589/c912e4156960a2ae2784)

If I request `/myBucket/myImage.jpg?w=100`, then update the base image in s3, and then reload `/myBucket/myImage.jpg?w=100`, I still get the original image. However, any requests for new modified images get the correct updated image (e.g. `/myBucket/myImage.jpg?w=333`)

Based on the documentation, having `s3reader2 -> checkForModifiedFiles` enabled should resolve this, but it does not. I've also played with disabling `s3reader2 -> cacheMetadata`, but the outcome is the same.

The problem obviously does not exist if the DiskCache plugin is disabled, but that's not really an option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are using cacheMetadata="false", which is a v4+ configuration parameter.

You are using the v3.4.3 dlls. Upgrading to v4 should resolve the issue. v3 does not have a way to fully disable metadata caching (Sliding expiration defaults to 1 hour).

related: [ImageResizer S3Reader2 Plugin 404 Error after image has been uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765665/imageresizer-s3reader2-plugin-404-error-after-image-has-been-uploaded)